# EPSON WF 6590 printer missing many features unter Windows 10, no driver update solves this

Tags: windows-10, drivers, printing, printer, device-manager

Epson seems to only support installation of drivers via Windows Update.

On Windows 10, the standard installed driver did not support anything, neither paper source could be selected, nor sort order or any other advanced features, like print quality.

Windows Update and driver update also did not provide any solution. There also is no setup tool by Epson.

How to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get the listed options with the **Standard Printer Driver v2.47.01** and 
**EPSON Universal Print Driver x64 (Core Files) v2.69.3**  from [here](https://epson.com/Support/Printers/All-In-Ones/WorkForce-Series/Epson-WorkForce-Pro-WF-6590/s/SPT_C11CD49201)

[image]

Comment: Many thanks! For me (in your right screenshot) it displays "EPSON Universal Print Driver" but it works just as well. I had to manually install it using "New Driver" and browsing to the path where I unzipped the Universal Print package.